# Merge multiple json objects in one json array

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to merge multiple array by common keys.I tried alot of functions and didn't get what i need. All the function give me an array with bad structure. So i need your help guys to get a proper one. I need the function in typescript or javascript This is my example

Array 1:

```
"Student":[ {
"id":91,
"name":"john",
"age":22

 },
{
  "id":11,
"name":"donald",
"age":20},
]
```

Array 2:

```
 "Courses":
  [
    {"id":91,
    "course name":"finance 1", 
    "course code":"fin12"}, 
    {"id":91, 
    "course name":"accounting",
    "course code":"acc1"}

  ]
```

Array 3:

```
    "Instructor": [
  {
    "id":91, 
    "instructor-name":"justin"

  }, 
  {
    "id":91,
    "instructor-name":"leonardo"

  }, 
  {
    "id":16,
    "instructor-name":"david"

  } 

]
```

Merge:

```
{
  "id": 91,
  "name": "john",
  "age": 22,
  "Course": [
    {
      "id": 91,
      "course name": "finance 1",
      "course code": "fin12"
    },
    {
      "id": 91,
      "course name": "accounting",
      "course code": "acc1"
    }
  ],
  "Instructor": [
    {
      "id": 91,
      "instructor name": "justin"
    },
    {
      "id": 91,
      "instructor name": "leonardo"
    }
  ]
}
```

If this isn't clear. Please inform me

Comment: did you try anything?

Comment: yes mergedByKey function and not what i want. even loadash wasn't good

Comment: can you share code which you tried?

Comment: const result = this.xresult.map(x => {
      return {
        this.xyresult.filter(
          c =>
            c["id"] === x["id"]
        ),
         x
      };
    });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can map through student array and filter another arrays based on id to get all course and instroctors.

```js
const studentArray =[ {
"id":91,
"name":"john",
"age":22

 },
{
  "id":11,
"name":"donald",
"age":20},
]

 const coursesArray = 
  [
    {"id":91,
    "course name":"finance 1", 
    "course code":"fin12"}, 
    {"id":91, 
    "course name":"accounting",
    "course code":"acc1"}

  ]

    const instructorArray = [
  {
    "id":91, 
    "instructor-name":"justin"

  }, 
  {
    "id":91,
    "instructor-name":"leonardo"

  }, 
  {
    "id":16,
    "instructor-name":"david"

  } 
]

const output = studentArray.map(item => {
    const id = item.id;
    const course = coursesArray.filter(course => id === course.id);
    const instructor = instructorArray.filter(i => id === i.id);
    return { ...item, course , instructor };
});

console.log(output)
```